# Conditional RestRepositoryResource

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Is it possible to have a conditional RestRepositoryResource in Spring Data Rest?
I have two Interfaces as Repositories and I want to expose either one or the other via the same URL.
Or alternatively, a configuration to configure which resource to expose on which URL.

Example:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "test")
public interface EnvironmentARepository extends JpaRepository<Long, EntityA> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "test")
public interface EnvironmentBRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, EntityB> {
}
```

If i use something like `@Conditional` it won't work (afterall it's not a bean, just an interface that will be instantiated somehow by Spring Data Rest).

I tested setting `exported = false` on one of them, but it seems like the framework registers the URL as not exported and the second interface can't overwrite that.

When I extend the `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
}
```

That config doesn't contain any ResourceMappings though (and that type is even deprecated).

Comment: What's the condition? Take a look at the [Conditionnal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) annotation and the many derivatives offered by [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/package-summary.html). A few of them are illustrated [here](https://blog.andresteingress.com/2017/09/21/spring-boot-conditional-annotations).

Comment: The thing is - do they work with these conditions? AFAIK they are not beans, but instantiated by the spring data (rest) code. I tried putting `@ConditionalOnExpression("false")` on top and it didn't change anything

Comment: I haven't tried myself. If you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I (or someone else) may be able to help.

Comment: Spring Profiles might help here i.e. expose one or the other based on the active profile. More info: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: to Tarin & Hay: profiles are implemented using Conditionals. Ie. they cannot offer anything more. And Conditional blocks bean registration based on condition. Meaning, that placing this annotation at place, where no bean is defined, has no effect. If you have 3 methods you want to selectively control, you probably could do it, via conditionals only via having one Controller per each permutation of properties and conditionally register those. But that's not a nice hack